# How to wrap images into a Excel Add-in 2003

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a excel add-in with several menu items. Each menu item embedded with a image.
I'm loading picture to menu item using LoadPicture function where I gave the absolute path to image location. In order to make the add-in distributable I need to provide a relative path.

Appropriate anyone can suggest me how to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your installation routine store the images in the same folder as the XLA addin and then use Thisworkbook.Path to construct an absolute path.

Or a simpler solution that would avoid the need for an install routine might be to embed the images as named pictures in a worksheet in the XLA, and then use CopyPicture and PasteFace.